# Do verbs refer to the tangible or the intangible?

Tags: meaning, verbs, parts-of-speech

This might be a dumb question but do verbs (or any other part of speech besides nouns) actually refer to elements of existence in a tangible way?

To be clear I would say that something is tangible if and only if you can perceive it using any of your 5 senses.
So with that in mind, would the act of say punching be something tangible or would the noun 'fist' and 'air' be the only tangible part and the verb 'punch[ing]' is simply serving as a connector/instruction.

Comment: Can you see, hear or feel a punch? If so, it's tangible by your definition.

Comment: Many (but not all) actions are readily observable if they happen nearby. As are many states (though many require instruments or feedback from 'patients' etc to be recordable). // Answers here will depend on what 'something / it' is stipulated as covering, and whether your stipulative definition of 'tangible' is acceptable. Have you dictionary endorsement?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of *tangible* as something to which we apply any of our five senses is over-restrictive when compared to dictionary definitions. For example:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangible)
> 1a: capable of being perceived especially by the sense of touch: Palpable
> b: substantially real : Material
>
> 2: capable of being precisely identified or realized by the mind
> *her grief was tangible*
>
> 3: capable of being appraised at an actual or approximate value
> *tangible assets*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tangible)
> real, existing; able to be shown or experienced:
>
> tangible evidence/proof/signs:
> *We can now see tangible evidence of economic renewal and growth*.
>
> a tangible achievement/benefit/effect:
> *Rewards can include financial payments, promotions, and other tangible benefits*
>
> tangible improvement/progress/results
> *They hope the meeting will achieve tangible results*.

The five senses send signals to our minds that permit it to interpret the world and to make a mental model of reality. Some concepts therefore are experienced or realised via the senses. "fragrance", "light", "sound" all come to mind.

But from the wider perspectives of being "realised by the mind" or being "able to be shown or experienced", something tangible need not be conditioned directly by the five senses. It is tangible to the mind because the mind realises or experiences it in other ways. "Grieving" come to mind as a real thing, as does its corresponding verb "to grieve". I suggest therefore that verbs may be as tangible as other concepts that derive directly from the five senses.

Answer (score 0):

> This might be a dumb question but do 'verbs' (or any other part of speech besides nouns) actually exist in a tangible way?

No. They are all descriptions of something. Descriptions are intangible.

Comment: 'Secondly, the designer has no freedom to synthesize the joint profiles based on tangible gait characteristics, such as walking speed, step length or step elevation.'
From the Cambridge English Corpus, via [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tangible). _Speed_ is non-concrete. // OP goes on to distinguish the word and what it is referring to in real life.

Comment: **has; to synthesize; (are) based** are the verbs in your example. **Speed** is a noun.

Answer (score 0):

Words are never tangible. Some of their ***referents*** are.

In Linguistics, a referent is

> the thing in the world that a word or phrase denotes or stands for.([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=referent%20meaning&oq=referent&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0i512l3j0i433i512j0i512l5.4560j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

It gets complicated with words which *refer* to an abstract concept. Can ***ideas*** be palpable? Can the referent of the verb ***think*** be tangible? In such cases both the word and its referent are not 'tangible' as you say.

Comment: 'Secondly, the designer has no freedom to synthesize the joint profiles based on tangible gait characteristics, such as walking speed, step length or step elevation.'
From the Cambridge English Corpus, via [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tangible). _Speed_ is non-concrete. // OP goes on to distinguish the word and what it is referring to in real life.